# Number of gifts given at the end of a party

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

So I'm working on a problem that has to do with Ramsey Theory. We have $n$ guests at a christmas party. We know two things about them. In any group of three there are two people who do not know each other. In any group of $7$ there are two people who $\bf{do}$ know each other. At the end of the party, people give gifts to the ones that they know. Prove that the number of gifts given is at most $6n$.

I've been trying for a while to figure this problem out. I started out by looking at a group of $7$. We know that two people do know eachother. But can we say anything else about these people? I've tried breaking 6 of them into groups of 3, and saw that 4 gifts are given out amongst a group of 3. But I can't really get any where.

Comment: does this mean in any group of three there are exactly two people who don't know each other and also in every group of seven exactly two people know each other?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, to be honest.

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, I would take it to mean that there are **at least** two people... not **exactly**...   Otherwise, it couldn't be in *any* group of 7.

Comment: @ Ricardo Saporta: I think you're right, because then $at most$ wouldn't make sense either.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut when you state that "this number is at most $6n$" I take it to mean that you are referring to the number of gifts given? Also, just to clarify, is knowing a mutual property (if A knows B, does B necessarily know A?)

Comment: @VincentTjeng: Yes, you can think of connecting them by a certain colored edge, while with those that don't a different color.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut In that case, unless I'm understanding your question wrongly, you have perhaps missed out some condition, since otherwise by Mantel's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel.27s_theorem the answer to your question would be $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $R(3, 7) = 23$, so there are at most 22 guests. [I don't know how to prove this, but since you're saying it's related to Ramsey Theory, I suppose you can quote this fact.]

**Hint:** Mantel's Theorem as Vincent suggested.